# localstack / how to create ec2 instances?

Tags: docker, localstack

I would like to use localstack to initiate virtual machine ec2 instances to install software that runs insider in docker - but I can't find a way to do this even if I light up the services required in the configuration. How can I get it so that I can activate two ec2 instances locally and install docker containers in each and then get them to communicate - is this even possible ?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?  Please let us know what you did in the end.

Comment: I would also like to know if we can create EC2 using localstack and install software on it.